# iPhoneでLaunchScreenの画像が表示されない

Tags: ios

iPhoneでLaunchScreenの画像が表示されません。

Launch Images Source : 設定なし
Launch Screen File : LaunchScreen

LaunchScreen.storyboardで、UIImageViewにAssets.xcassetsの画像を設定 (1xのみ。1080x1920)

の状態で、LaunchScreenが白一色になってしまいます。
シミュレーターでは表示されるのですが、実機では表示されません。

どのようにしたら表示されるようになるでしょうか?

Comment: すみません、
.xcassetsでなくプロジェクトの画像を設定してみたところ、できたのですが、
新規プロジェクトに同じ設定をしてもうまくいきませんでした。
xcassetsに設定しなおしても同様です。

プロジェクトをクリーン、アプリをアンインストール、Derived Dataを削除など思いつくことを何でもやってみましたがだめでした。

Comment: 誰か答えてはくださらないでしょうか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

画像名を変えてみて下さい。
それで上手く行くことがあります

Comment: 画像名を変えてみたらうまくいきました。ありがとうございます。